# Core file complete nonsense or could this code really have thrown a SIGFPE?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, coredump, sigfpe

My core file claims that a SIGFPE was thrown from

gcc-4.3.4/include/c++/4.3.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h

on line 176.  This is here:

```
  template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Distance>
    inline void
    advance(_InputIterator& __i, _Distance __n)
    {
          // concept requirements -- taken care of in __advance
176---->  typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type __d = __n;
          std::__advance(__i, __d, std::__iterator_category(__i));
    }
```

this is inside another function I have that is indeed calling advance surrounding by code that isn't doing any floating point arithmetic.  The code is compiled with optimizations (but has debugging symbols), so things may be a big obfuscated.

Is my core file just telling me complete nonsense or is there a way this could make sense?

Comment: SIGFPE doesn't necessarily correspond to floating-point arithmetic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE.

Comment: Could you show the `bt full` output?

Comment: @Oli thanks to pointing me to look at general math bugs, not just floating point ones.  It turns out `% 0` can raise SIGFPE too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to my own question, what happened is that optimizer took code that looked like this:

```
int which = RANDOM % somecontainer.size();
std::advance(it, which);
```

and combined them.  This is why it appears the signal was raised from inside std::advance.  Following Oli's comment, SIGFPE can occur when you take the modulus with respect to 0, even though it isn't a floating point operation.  There was a different bug which allowed `somecontainer` to be empty in a corner case.